# Script does not have permission to perform that action after authorization granted CalendarApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been executing a gscript for a couple years now, but just today I started seeing the following when I try to execute it:

> The script does not have permission to perform that action. Required
>   permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar ||
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly ||
>   https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds)

I went ahead and deauthorized my script from my Account permissions page and re-ran the script to force re-auth, but I'm still seeing the error.

The line in question is simply trying to do:

```
CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From what error you've encountered, it indicates that the script lacking the authorization needed to run. When a script is run in the Script Editor or from a custom menu item an authorization dialog is presented to the user. However, when a script is run from a trigger, embedded with a Google Sites page, or run as a service, the dialog cannot be presented and this error is shown.

If the script contains new unauthorized services, you must re-authorize the script. Here's a documentation on how to [troubleshoot this type of error in Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/install-addons#uninstalling_editor_add-ons).

If a trigger continues to fire and cause this error, you can access your triggers by doing the following:

> 1. Select **Edit > All your triggers** in the Apps Script editor. The resulting dialog shows all active triggers running on your account.
> 2. Find the offending trigger in the list.
> 3. Click the clear icon next to the trigger name to remove it.
> 4. Click **Save** to record the deletion.
>
> You can also remove problematic add-on triggers by [uninstalling the add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/install-addons#uninstalling_editor_add-ons).

Comment: In my case deleting trigger, and readding it solved the problem. Thanks.